# PullReplication to fetch data from couch base into the Couch Lite not working in Android

Tags: android, database, couchbase-lite

I'm using Couchbase Lite DB to fetch data from a Couchbase server. In the Android Emulator it's working fine but in Android devices (Mobiles) it's showing a timeout exception and indeed is taking too much time.

Ideas?

Comment: May you provide your logs when connect to mobile device? Which version of Android are you using and any chance of providing some replication code?  How big are the documents you pulling down to the device(s) ?

Answer (score 0):

For your replication code, can also take a look at the [Replication Guide](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html) to verify where the potential issue may be but sometimes it can easily be a network connectivity problem too.